# Vue js using scope-slot and trying to use a property from within but having no visibility

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using vue form wizard https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard (and vue  form generator https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator)

here the complete example, the problem is that when changing tabs, the text is not updating, as `this.buttonNextText` is undefined in the method `handleTabChange`

```
<template>
  <div class="myprefix-step-cash">
    <form-wizard @complete="onComplete"
                 @change="handleTabChange"
                 color="gray"
                 error-color="#a94442"
                 :ref="'vuewizard'"
    >
      <tab-content title="Personal details"
                   icon="ti-user" :before-change="validateFirstTab">
        <vue-form-generator :model="model"
                            :schema="firstTabSchema"
                            :options="formOptions"
                            ref="firstTabForm"
        >

        </vue-form-generator>
      </tab-content>
      <tab-content title="Additional Info"
                   icon="ti-settings" :before-change="validateSecondTab">
        <vue-form-generator :model="model"
                            :schema="secondTabSchema"
                            :options="formOptions"
                            ref="secondTabForm"
        >
        </vue-form-generator>

      </tab-content>
      <tab-content title="Last step"
                   icon="ti-check">
        <h4>Your json is ready!</h4>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <pre v-if="model" v-html="prettyJSON(model)"></pre>
        </div>
      </tab-content>

      <template slot="footer" slot-scope="props">
        <div class="dummy">
          <!--<wizard-button :style="props.fillButtonStyle">Cancel</wizard-button>-->
          <wizard-button @click.native="props.prevTab()" class="myprefix-form-prev"  v-if="buttonPrevDisplay" v-html="buttonPrevText"></wizard-button>
          <wizard-button @click.native="props.nextTab()" class="myprefix-form-next"  v-if="buttonNextDisplay" v-html="buttonNextText"></wizard-button>
        </div>
      </template>

    </form-wizard>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import VueFormGenerator from "vue-form-generator";
  export default {
    mounted: function () {

    },

    methods: {

      handleTabChange: function (prevIndex, nextIndex) {
        let app = this;
        console.error('app.buttonNextText: ' + app.buttonNextText);
        console.error('prev: ' + prevIndex);
        console.error('next: ' + nextIndex);
        if(nextIndex == 0){
          app.buttonNextText = myprefix_global_translate_obj.btn_txt_tab1;
        }else{
          app.buttonNextText = myprefix_global_translate_obj.btn_txt_default;
        }
        if(nextIndex >= 1){
          app.buttonPrevDisplay = true;
        }else{
          app.buttonPrevDisplay = false;
        }
        if(nextIndex == 2 ){
        }
        console.error("tab changing :DD");
      },
      onComplete: () => {

      },



      validateFirstTab: function () {
        return this.$refs.firstTabForm.validate();
      },
      validateSecondTab: function () {
        return this.$refs.secondTabForm.validate();
      },

      zipcode: (value) => {
        let re = /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/;

        if (!re.test(value)) {
          return ["Invalid Zip Code."];
        } else {
          return []
        }
      },

      prettyJSON: function (json) {
        if (json) {
          json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 4);
          json = json.replace(/&/g, '&').replace(/</g, '<').replace(/>/g, '>');
          return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
            var cls = 'number';
            if (/^"/.test(match)) {
              if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'key';
              } else {
                cls = 'string';
              }
            } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
              cls = 'boolean';
            } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
              cls = 'null';
            }
            return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
          });
        }
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        buttonPrevDisplay: false,
        buttonPrevText: myprefix_global_translate_obj.btn_txt_back,
        buttonNextDisplay: true,
        buttonNextText: myprefix_global_translate_obj.btn_txt_tab1,
        model: {
          loanAmount: '',
          zip: '',
          email: '',
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          email: '',
          streetName: '',
          streetNumber: '',
          city: '',
          country: ''
        },
        formOptions: {
          validationErrorClass: "myprefix-has-error",
          validationSuccessClass: "myprefix-has-success",
          validateAfterChanged: true
        },
        firstTabSchema: {
          fields: [
            {
              type: "input",
              inputType: "text",
              label: myprefix_global_translate_obj.how_much_cash,
              placeholder: myprefix_global_translate_obj.how_much_cash_ph,
              model: "loanAmount",
              required: true,
              validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
              styleClasses: 'myprefix-loanAmount'
            },
            {
              type: "input",
              inputType: "text",
              label: myprefix_global_translate_obj.what_zip,
              placeholder: myprefix_global_translate_obj.what_zip_ph,
              model: "zip",
              required: true,
              hint: myprefix_global_translate_obj.what_zip_hint,
              validator: this.zipcode,
              styleClasses: 'myprefix-zip'
            },
            {
              type: "input",
              inputType: "text",
              label: myprefix_global_translate_obj.what_email,
              model: "email",
              required: true,
              validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.email,
              styleClasses: 'myprefix-email'
            },
          ]
        },
        secondTabSchema: {
          fields: [

            {
              type: "input",
              inputType: "text",
              label: myprefix_global_translate_obj.what_last_name,
              model: "lastName",
              required: true,
              validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
              styleClasses: 'myprefix-lastname'
            },

            {
              type: "input",
              inputType: "text",
              label: myprefix_global_translate_obj.what_first_name,
              model: "firstName",
              required: true,
              validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
              styleClasses: 'myprefix-firstname'
            },
            {
              type: "input",
              inputType: "text",
              label: "Street name",
              model: "streetName",
              required: true,
              validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
              styleClasses: 'col-9'
            },
            {
              type: "input",
              inputType: "text",
              label: "Street number",
              model: "streetNumber",
              required: true,
              validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
              styleClasses: 'col-3'
            },

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

Comment: When the component is created, is `myprefix_global_translate_obj` defined and populated?

Comment: @StephenThomas yes... the problem really isn't that variable. It is that the scope of the `<template slot="footer" slot-scope="props">` seems to have no possible access from within to the vue environment on the level of the component.  See here: https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard/issues/24#issuecomment-312690602

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be exactly the case for you, but I got similar issue with an accordion expanded/collapsed state. The problem was simply that I needed to specify in the `v-bind` directive the property/value I wanted exposed to the child components.

```
<template>
   <div>
      <label @click="toggle">
         <slot name="trigger" :expanded="state"></slot>
      </label>

      <slot :expanded="state"></slot>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: 'Accordion',

      data() {
         return {
            state: false
         }
      },

      methods: {
         toggle() {
            this.state = !this.state;
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

The page with components:

```
<accordion v-for="(rs, index) in data " :key="rs.id" class="accordion text-left mt-4">
   <template slot="trigger" slot-scope="state" :tabindex="index">
      <!-- some contents -->
   </template>

   <slidable slot-scope="state"
             :active="state.expanded"
             v-html="rs.content">
   </slidable>
</accordion>
```

Here `state.expanded` would be the accordion state, and I was able to access it from another child component (`<slidable />`).

---

### EDIT

Actually, I think I spotted your problem. You need to bind the events with their names in kebab-case, like so:

```
<form-wizard @on-change="handleTabChange" 
             @on-complete="onComplete">
    // ...
```

Resources:

- https://binarcode.github.io/vue-form-wizard/#/?id=events
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

Comment: very interesting, and I eventually managed to udnerstand it as well. The confusing part is a bit that you have an object called `state`, and you store it in a property `expanded`. Then you reassign a new local variable and call it state in slot scope... the problem with me is that I don't have access to the parent implementation, at is a library...